# About comparison operators on Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Javascript, if i do the following command :

```
if (cond1 && cond2) {
}
```

The parser will stop if cond1 is false, no need to check cond2. This is good for performance.

In the same manner :

```
if (cond1 || cond2) {
}
```

If cond1 is true, there is no need to check cond2.

Is there something similar on newer Delphi versions ? I'm on the 10.4

Thanx

Comment: Nitpick regarding the title of this question: in my world, a comparison operator is an operator like `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, or `>=`. `and`, `or`, `not` etc. are "boolean operators".

Comment: This is available with **every** Delphi version that ever existed. Have you even tested this yourself before asking?

Comment: Although this Q is fine and allowed me to give an A that focuses on a part I find important and often overlooked (that this is more about code conciseness and readability than performance), you could also have found this out by looking at the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Complete_Versus_Short-Circuit_Boolean_Evaluation) about boolean operators. That's even better than testing it!

Comment: Why didn't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Delphi compiler supports [boolean short-circuit evaluation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Complete_Versus_Short-Circuit_Boolean_Evaluation). It can be enabled or disabled using a [compiler directive](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Boolean_short-circuit_evaluation_(Delphi_compiler_directive)), but it is enabled by default, and often Delphi code *assumes* it to be enabled.

This is very often used not only to increase performance, but to write code more succinctly.

For instance, I often write things like

```
if Assigned(X) and X.Enabled then
  X.DoSomething;
```

or

```
if (delta > 0) and ((b - a)/delta > 1000) then
  raise Exception.Create('Too many steps.');
```

or

```
if TryStrToInt(s, i) and InRange(i, Low(arr), High(arr)) and (arr[i] = 123) then
  DoSomething
```

or

```
i := 1;
while (i <= s.Length) and IsWhitespace(s[i]) do
begin
  // ...
  Inc(i);
end;
```

or

```
ValidInput := TryStrToInt(s, i) and (i > 18) and (100 / i > 2)
```

In all these examples, I rely on the evaluation to stop "prematurely". Otherwise, I'd run into access violations, division by zero errors, random behaviour, etc.

In fact, every day I write code that assumes that boolean short-circuit evaluation is on!

It's idiomatic Delphi.

Comment: can I recommend that you search for duplicates when you encounter a question that you expect already to have been answered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You are right of course that this has been answered before in various forms, albeit sometimes indirectly. Although neither of the two Qs you mention asks the exact same Q or is of particularly high quality, they definitely do answer the Q. However, if you just want to find the answer, you very much need not SO at all -- you just need to read the docs. An SO answer can give a bit more context. I imagine it doesn't hurt if there are a duplicate or two with different wordings for people who search the WWW. Or do you suggest I remove this A so that the Q can be removed?

Comment: Don't remove anything. Dupehammer it. Which I did.